# Vertical paging and columns

Tags: html, css, layout

Is there a way in HTML and/or CSS to automatically break multi-column content into pages by height? For instance, if you want to display an e-book in a web page and use multiple columns, you might want to display 1 page = 2 columns in the viewport at once, then have a vertical break to simulate page breaks, and have the next two column page.

For instance, if I wanted to display an entire chapter in a two-column format on one HTML page, if I just did `column-count:2`, then each column would probably be really long and you've have to scroll all the way to the bottom to read the first column, then all the way back to the top to continue to the second column. What I'm looking for is a way to avoid having to scroll back to the top but still use columns.

I realize this can be done with Javascript, but I'm *not asking about using javascript*. I'm only interested in pure HTML/CSS techniques. If there is no way to do it, I already know how to do it in JS.

**Edit:**
Here is a simple illustration of what I'm looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/xGqAC/7/embedded/result/

To be clear, I don't specifically have an implementation in Javascript, I just know that it can be done there, and I imagine there are already multi-column libraries that can do this, but again, that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Could you show what it looks like with js, so we know what you want to achieve? maybe with a JSFiddle?

Comment: @ToonCasteele: Added a plaintext illustration.

Comment: Assuming no one ever solved this...

Comment: That's correct. I haven't seen any solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for via CSS only is not possible.

But you can set an height for your columns and a width and if you do not set any colum-count,  columns will be added as many as needed , this can get you to the closest compromised i can think of ... if column is supported in your browser

```
html, body {
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
body {
  width:940px;
  column-width:450px;
  column-gap:10px;
  column-rule:solid;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 3px;
  overflow:auto;
  margin:auto;
}
```

Nothing is like PDF in CSS (media web/media print) :)
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hxcIt